# 'openalpr/alpr.h' file not found when using opncv in ios

Tags: ios

I followed the link [openalpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr). The bundles  are installed but the following error shows

```
openalpr/alpr.h file not found error.
```

How to resolve that?